# How can I make multiple controller on single view in CakePHP3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How can I make multiple controller on single view in CakePHP3?

Please kindly see [image: this image link][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ZER.png).

Comment: To me this sounds as if you need to learn abot the basics of associations. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html** | **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data**

Comment: View cells might be useful - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html